Implementation of a variable-detent rotary encoder
I'm curious as to how a variable-detent rotary encoder would be implemented. For example, the Rivian R2 dials on the steering wheel have this effect, and I'm interested in how they made it work. Also, would it be possible to have any semblance of analog feel to knobs that have this functionality? In other words, could a knob be made that has variable detents but which feels like an analog knob?

One might be implemented as so: 
https://hackaday.com/2022/03/13/haptic-smart-knob-does-several-jobs/

Setting this as wiki for anyone to expand -- I'm not familiar enough with this project to summarize, but others may be, or may wish to expand this. (Also, not simply commenting the link, because it's still an answer.)

Thank you so much! Open source is fantastic.
